# Display a boolean value in English in a MsgBox?

Tags: windows, vbscript, boolean, wsh

In VisualBasicScript there is a way to print the value of a Boolean variable in English indifferently of the language of the OS?.

If you don't know what I'm talking about then what I mean for example is that I have my OS (Windows 8.1) in Spanish and when I run the next orders:

```
Bool = True
MsgBox Bool
```

...It prints "***Verdadero***" which is the Spanish translation to "***True***".

And If I try the same using `WScript.Echo` it prints the numeric representation of the booleans, but well really I'm only interested to do the right conversion for a `MsgBox`.

I'm not looking for solutions like '*you can check the boolean value like this*':

```
If Bool = True then
    Msgbox("True")
Else
    MsgBox("False")
End If
```

I'm just asking that if this can be done without writting conditional checks or other involved code, just ...exist any VBS method to convert/print a Boolean value correctlly?.

Comment: _Why_ would you want to do that? A user will most likely have the Spanish version of Windows if they understand Spanish, so Verdadero is probably the _right_ thing to put in the message box.

Comment: @paxdiablo But not for me, I hate this kind of programming terminologies translations to other languages (even translated to my language), I would like to show in a MsgBox a question with the equivalent Boolean result in English (True or False) and I would like to know the better/smarter code that I could write to do this (maybe using an existing VBS method to convert the Bool?) because now I need to duplicate a Msgbox just to show "True" and other Msgbox to show "False" with a conditional to check the value of the Boolean var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure *why* you'd want to force English onto someone who has clearly set their locale to Spain, it appears to me they'd *want* to get the Spanish variant.

However, if you're hell-bent on doing it, one way is with a function called, for example, `EnglishBool()` which takes a boolean and returns the English string `"True"` or `"False"`, something like:

```
Function EnglishBool (boolValue)
    If boolValue Then
        EnglishBool = "True"
    Else
        EnglishBool = "False"
    End If
End Function
```

Then you call it with:

```
MsgBox EnglishBool (Bool)
```

It's still complex in that you have to define the function but the places where you *use* that function are pretty simple one-liners, no different really to the simple `MsgBox Bool` (at least in terms of source code).

Comment: thankyou for the answer but could you clarify if exist a native method provided in the VBS language to properlly print a boolean value as `True` of `False` like using a common `.ToString` method extension seen in other languages?. PS: Tried with `CStr(Boolean)` and I get the same Spanish result.

Comment: @ElektroStudios, I don't know of one. There _may_ be but you may also find you have to resort to my function-based one.